# Compare dates from MySql and Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datepicker

How do i compare **Multiple dates** coming from mysql with the **Clicked date** from jquery datepicker?.

For suppose i have the following dates coming from mysql in loop.

```
02-06-2014
04-06-2014
10-06-2014
12-06-2014
17-06-2014
20-06-2014
```

And This is my Date from jQuery Datepicker Which changes everytime when i click on it.

```
12-06-2014
```

If 12-06-2014 is present in my mysql resultset, echo "yes"; or else "no";

Comment: what you have tried for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? Hint: Take all of your mysql dates in an array and than simply check with in_array function.

Comment: I have used date_diff function and.. i exploded it to make 12062014 which didn't worked for me.

Comment: I cannot see any dates here, but maybe I've been inhabiting the world of SQL a little too long. These are plain old, ordinary strings.

Comment: @ Strawberry i have mentioned. my dates are coming in a loop from mysql resultset. Anyhow how are those strings can be compared with the clicked date on datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker has a method that you set in options called onSelect. You can do something like this:

```
arOfDates = [your, dates, here];
$('#datepickerID').datepicker({
     onSelect: function(dateSelected){
         $.each(arOfDates, function (key, value){
              if(value == dateSelected) console.log(value, dateSelected);
         }
         //or without iteration
         if($.inArray(dateSelected, arOfDates) != -1) console.log(dateSelected);
     }
});
```

Comment: I dint get this - arOfDates = [your, dates, here];

Comment: That would be the array containing your dates.

What my answer does is compare the dates when the date is selected from the datepicker.

Comment: yes i got it...  am trying to put my resultset in array. Thanks